# How to write a generic services for HTTP call and used its response/error in module file

Tags: angular

I am new to angular i want to know how to write a generic http call which returns 
result/error back to module file.

below is an auth service function which i have written :

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    const body = new HttpParams()
      .set('email', username)
      .set('password', password);
    return this.http.post('http://192.168.31.73:8080/istar/rest/auth/login', body, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

    })
      // See below - subscribe() is still necessary when using post().
      .subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data)
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(data));

      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
          // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
          console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
        } else {
          // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
          // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
          console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
        }
      }

      );
  }
```

currently url is static i want to make in dynamic so that whatever the url and parameter i pass it will make an http call return the respone.

below is component file logic to make this service call :

```
const fetchdata = this.auth.login(this.form.get('email').value, this.form.get('password').value)
```

but i dont know how can i fetch the result from fetch data variable. its type is subscriber.

Comment: Don't subscribe in the service. Subscribing is the job of the caller component. You can use the [`do` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do) to store the current user in local storage in case of success, and still return the observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to subscribe to each http call to get the required data from the api as by default all the rest calls are cold in nature and you need to subscribe for it to return stream of data.

You can end up writing a generic function which will subscribe but i dnt think writing `.subscribe` for every call makes a difference and also you will need custom interfaces some time in future to make model data which will be handled in the component like

```
   this._service.getObservable().subscribe(res => {
      //data from service
    });
```

For generic error handling you can look at [**http interceptors**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/services)

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()
export class AngularInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).do(event => {}, err => {
        if(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse){
            console.log("Error Caught By Interceptor");
            //Observable.throw(err);
        }
    });
  }
}
```